# Numerical Solution of transient heat equation with source in cylindrical co-ordinates

Tags: numerical-methods, heat-equation, cylindrical-coordinates

I am attempting to use the finite difference scheme on a uniform grid in $r$. I have a no flux boundary condition at $r=0$ which is proving to be a pain to implement. I'm having difficulty in doing this, I have checked and rechecked my code and derivation of the code but I cannot see an error. I am using the Crank-Nicholson method as I'm told that nice and stable and although I get something nice, physically it's wrong. The stencil I get is:
$$2\alpha u_{i+1,1}-(2\alpha+1)u_{i+1,0}=-2\alpha u_{i,1}+(2\alpha-1)u_{i,0}-\frac{1}{2}(Q_{i+1,0}+Q_{i,0})\delta t$$
This doesn't work and I don't know what's going on.

Do I need to abandon this completely or is there something I can do to rescue this?

Comment: $r$ is which coordinate?

Comment: Could you show the steps how you got from the PDE to the iterative scheme?

Comment: The $i$ index denotes time and the $j$ index denotes $r$. To obtain the stencil for the inner BC, which is the no flux condition is obtained by:

Comment: The $i$ index denotes time and the $j$ index denotes $r$. To obtain the stencil for the inner BC, which is the no flux condition is obtained by:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\Bigg|_{r=r_{j},t=t_{i+\frac{1}{2}}}=D\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial r^{2}}\Bigg|_{r=r_{j},t=t_{i+\frac{1}{2}}}+\frac{D}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\Bigg|_{r=r_{j},t=t_{i+\frac{1}{2}}}+Q(t,r)\Bigg|_{r=r_{j},t=t_{i+\frac{1}{2}}}$$

Now for the BC at $r=0$ take the limit and using L'Hopital's rule one obtains:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=2D\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial r^{2}}+Q(t,0)$$

Comment: The same process is again done but now the no flux condition at the origin reduces to:

$$u_{i,2}=u_{i,0}$$

This is then inserted into the stencil for the boundary to get the equation in the OP.